# Magento REST is not Found after http://{magentoHost}/api/

Tags: api, magento, rest

I am trying to access rest API for Guest User through 
 `http://localhost/b_marketing/api/rest/products`, but the page redirects to 404 page. I have checked  retrive catalog products in ACL attributes RULES, REST - attributes and REST - ROLES, correctly. It also works correctly on my other project by using these all configurations.
There is one thing I need to mention here that my project works only when I use `http://localhost/b_marketing/index.php` , despite of setting up the htaccess rewrites and setting rewrite from admin panel. My apache rewrites are also set. 
When I use `http://localhost/b_marketing/api/?wsdl` it works and some xml returns. 
But I cannot use `http://localhost/b_marketing/api/rest/products` 
 The Response Header is always 404.

I also cannot access REST API using `http://localhost/b_marketing/index.php/api/rest/products` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have rewrite rule in .htaccess.

1. Go to magento root folder, in your case it is b_marketing
2. Open .htaccess file in any editor
3. Locate rewrite rule for api

If you don't have .htaccess file in place, you may consider to copy fron original
Magento packagem

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer it worked! :)
I just created the .htaccess and placed the api ReWrite Code, then it started to fetch api data. Here is the .htaccess code:<br />

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
 # Turn mod_rewrite on
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /b_marketing

  

 ## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing
     RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

     ## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

         RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

</IfModule>

Comment: How can i use REST API without oAuth in the live server? @ Krishna Sunuwar

Answer (score 1):

## If you run nginx:

.htaccess is not supported. Edit the nginx configuration and add the line:

```
location /api {
    rewrite ^/api/rest /api.php?type=rest last;
}
```

I read that that line sometimes is already there however with the the word `break` instead of `last`. Thats wrong, change it to `last`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use `-MultiViews`. As the `api.php` and `/api` path have the same name (without extension), Apache might resolve `api` automatically to `api.php` and cause trouble.